# Alter heroku's config var in my rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I intent to change it when the admin user log in and log out. Is it possible and how can I do it?

Comment: Why do you want to change a global configuration variable, when an admin signs in? What do your try to achieve?

Comment: Because if an admin is not logged the app will show a message to the users.
I don't know if this is a terrible thing to do! is it?

Comment: Why don't you store that information in the database, in Redis or Memcached. Furthermore how do you plan to determine that an admin is still online (without reloading the page on a regular base)?

Comment: It's a good ideia to store in the database. I was thinking that when the admin logs in, change the value and then tha var will be intact untill he logs out again, then, back the value.

Answer (score 0):

You can change environment variables through the `ENV` hash.

For example, you can have a method like this which gets called when the logout button is clicked:

```
def logout_admin
  ENV["ADMIN_LOGGED_IN"] = false
end
```

This isn't a typical way to do auth. Usually people use a session token in the database. Really you can use the ENV the hash the same as global variables (it won't persist if you reboot the rails app, anyway).